# Hibernate issue - missing association in @JoinTable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring and Hibernate. I have following JPA mapping:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "chg_type")
public abstract class EntitlementChange extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    protected static List<Argument<?>> copy(List<Argument<?>> arguments) {
        return arguments.stream()
            .map(Argument::getCopy)
            .collect(toList());
    }

    protected EntitlementChange(List<Argument<?>> arguments) {
        super();

        this.arguments = copy(arguments);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = SequenceOf.ENTITLEMENT_CHANGE_IDS)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SequenceOf.ENTITLEMENT_CHANGE_IDS, sequenceName = SequenceOf.ENTITLEMENT_CHANGE_IDS, allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    private List<Argument<?>> arguments;
}
```

And entity which inherits from EntitlementChange class.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(EntitlementModification.DISCRIMINATOR)
public class EntitlementModification extends EntitlementChange {

    public static final String DISCRIMINATOR = "modify";

    public EntitlementModification(List<Argument<?> arguments) {
        super(arguments);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm creating new EntitlementModification object with list of arguments and saving it to database using transaction:

```
@Transactional
public EntitlementChange createEntitlementChange(List<Argument<?>> arguments) {

    EntitlementChange change = new EntitlementModification(arguments);

    return entitlementChangeRepository.save(change);
}
```

I get EntitlementChange object with new ID which contain arguments list with assigned ID's too. When we look to the database, we can see that arguments entries are created, EntitlementChange entry is created, but association in joining table is not created. So when I'm getting EntitlementChange object using repository, arguments are null. Argument class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "arg_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = LongStringArgument.class, name = LongStringArgument.DISCRIMINATOR),
        @Type(value = StringArgument.class, name = StringArgument.DISCRIMINATOR),
        @Type(value = BooleanArgument.class, name = BooleanArgument.DISCRIMINATOR),
        @Type(value = SelectOneArgument.class, name = SelectOneArgument.DISCRIMINATOR),
        @Type(value = MultiSelectArgument.class, name = MultiSelectArgument.DISCRIMINATOR),
        @Type(value = IntegerArgument.class, name = IntegerArgument.DISCRIMINATOR)
})
public abstract class Argument<T> extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = SequenceOf.ARGUMENT_IDS)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SequenceOf.ARGUMENT_IDS, sequenceName = SequenceOf.ARGUMENT_IDS, allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    protected Argument() {
        super();
    }

    public Argument(String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract T getValue();

    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract Argument<T> getCopy();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Argument))
            return false;

        Argument<?> argument = (Argument<?>) o;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(getName(), argument.getName())
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                .append(getName())
                .toHashCode();
    }
}
```

What could be a reason of this strange behaviour?

Comment: Are you trying to create a one-to-many relationship between two of your tables?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create one-to-many relationship between Argument and EntitlementChange entities and this relationship has to be unidirectional.

Comment: can you update your question to show the argument class.

Comment: Done as you asked.